# How to use Lucene and JPA?

Tags: jpa, lucene, eclipselink

I would like to use Lucene to provide full text search capability on some of my java objects stored with EclipseLink in my Postgresql database.

I saw Hibernate has an integrated solution for Lucene called Hibernate Search, but I can't find anything for EclipseLink. Is there a solution out there for EclispeLink? if not I have a vague idea of what I should do to handle Lucene indexing when adding and removing objects but I would really appreciate if somebody could provide me with a nice tutorial on this topic.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There WAS Compass.  However, it was a one-man project, and that developer stopped working on it back in 2009.  He moved on to another one-man project, called [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

That project is a standalone search engine, competing with Apache Solr... rather than an embedded library competing with Apache Lucene and Hibernate Search.

Unfortunately, I don't really know of any other serious alternatives for integrating EclipseLink with Apache Lucene.  EclipseLink has gathered a lot of mindshare since Oracle changed its name from TopLink, gave it away, and declared it to be a reference implementation.  EclipseLink MOXy is a fantastic JAX-B implementation with some really cool extensions.  However, for core database interaction... Hibernate is still the more mature and adopted JPA implementation by a mile.

On the other hand, the Hibernate Search wrapper for Lucene **does** support using Hibernate in JPA 2 mode rather than its classic API.  In my opinion, it integrates a bit cleaner with JPA rather than the old Hibernate API anyway.

So unless you're using proprietary EclipseLink extensions that have you locked-in, you might consider swapping out your JPA provider if you want easy Lucene integration.  If your entity classes are already JPA-annotated, it should be a simple matter of updating your `persistence.xml` file (and your Maven POM, or however you manage your JAR dependencies).

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at all these. I think I will move to Hibernate indeed... It also has support for spatial queries and many more that I need and that EclipseLink unfortunately doesn't support.

Comment: It's 2017 now and Elasticsearch is huge. I found this tutorial, Elasticsearch and Hibernate, very appropriate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufaI51o_7WI